# Convert Future result into json

Tags: scala, akka

I have the two model for communication:

```
case class Post(id: Int, name: String, text: String)
case class Tag(id: Int, name: String)
```

And i create json format for this models:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
object myFormats {
  implicit val postFormat = Json.format[Post]
  implicit val tagFormat = Json.format[Tag]
}
```

Then i create service (actor) which can return OkResponse or BadResponse

```
sealed trait Response
case class OkResponse[T](model: T) extends Response
case class BadResponse(msg: String) extends Response


// easy example  
case class Message(id: Int)

class MyActorService extends Actor {

     def receive = {
        case Message(id) => 
          if (id == 0) {
             sender ! OkResponse(Post(1, "foo", "bar"))
          }  else if (id == 1) {
             sender ! OkResponse(Tag(1, "tag"))
          } else {
             sender ! BadResponse("id overflow")
          }
     }
}
```

Then i want convert model OkResponse to Json value:

```
(myActorService ? Message(1)).mapTo[Response].map {
  case BadResponse(msg) => println(msg)

  case OkResponse(model) => 
    println(Json.toJson(model)) 
}
```

But this not compiled because `No Json serializer found for type Any. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`

How to talk scala about Type of my Model? What is the best way to save type for work with future in scala?

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `model` value in your `OkResponse` is not known, so you get the bottom type `Any`.

You could pattern match on the model of your `OkResponse`.

```
(myActorService ? Message(1)).mapTo[Response].map {
  case BadResponse(msg) => println(msg)

  case OkResponse(post: Post) => 
    println(Json.toJson(post))

  case OkResponse(tag: Tag) => 
    println(Json.toJson(tag)) 
}
```

Comment: yes this work as expected, but i have many models, is it possible without matching all models?

Comment: You need the type of the model to get the `Json` type class for that model, which format your model to json. Maybe you can give us some more context in your question. Now it looks like you want to turn a message id (an Int) into json, irrespective of the model type.

Comment: This the whole question :). I might create some like `MainObject` and then extend `Post` and `Tag`  with it, and create json writer for ADT, but maybe is it possible automatically with TypeTag passing for example.

Comment: @mike It might be easier to create a `MyActorService` for every model type, instead of using one `MyActorService` to return every model type. Then you will know which type of model you will receive.

Comment: yes, you right, but i want to know how to create solution with generics

Comment: @mike you can do pattern match for your message inside `myFormats` taking message as the input parameter and passing appropriate `Json.format` to `Json.toJson` explicitly. Everything will be in one place then

Comment: If you use json4s  library you  dont need to explicitly  define your json expected  type in the OK RESPONSE method .  U only need to the msg for serialization(try to return an option of a msg, so u can pattern  match it)